# How to measure linear displacement in real-time?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, sensors, positions-measurement

I'm trying to sense the position and orientation of an object in real-time using an Arduino. I'm able to measure orientation with ease using a 9-DOF IMU.

I cant seem to figure out how to measure linear position. I tried integrating the linear acceleration readings from the IMU (compensated for gravity) to get velocity then integrating again to get position and using filters at each step. Despite using filters I still get a very inaccurate result.

Unless there's some holy grail algorithm that can extract linear position from an IMU I have to turn to other sensors or devices. Are there any sensors/devices that measure linear position/displacement with respect to an origin (start position).

**Does the following device or anything similar to it exist?**

Is there such thing as device that has a cable/tether that once pulled measures the displacement based on how far its been pulled out and in what direction? (perhaps by sensing tensile forces/directions on the cable?)

[image]

Comment: Good imu for position tracking are very expensive. Instead of origin, can you track relative to some beacon?

Comment: Yes, such "draw wire sensors" exist. But where sensors are concerned, context matters a lot and you've given none. Normally use an IMU where no other sensors will suffice because the object has too many degress of freedom. Asking for a draw wire sensor implies your degrees of freedom are very limited.

Comment: An IMU can augment an absolute position sensor, but as you've just experienced, it can't _be_ an absolute position sensor.  There are innumerable ways to do absolute position sensing -- you need to tell us more about what you're doing before we can really help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such thing as device that has a cable/tether that once pulled measures the displacement based on how far its been pulled out and in what direction? (perhaps by sensing tensile forces/directions on the cable?)

Yes, a 'linear transducer' or 'string pot' will give you an accurate distance indication, but not the direction. Maybe you can use 2 such devices, to give the distance & angle by triangulation.

Comment: Two would give you the location if your gizmo is constrained to a plane, or otherwise has two degrees of freedom.  You'd need three for 3D motion.